# Moving a document library - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

We archive some of our older document libraries and I am not sure how it was done previously (possibly just moved using explorer). But I think I am correct in saying document library's shouldn't be moved this way? Is there a procedure to follow to move a document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are couple of ways to get this done.

- Move using the explorer which you already know.
- Use the OOTB features called [information management policies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9?CorrelationId=3e6599d2-c1d5-42df-816b-22e27e02561e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA101631505)
- You can write a workflow which move the documents from one library to other. [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYj6bhvzYvI) or [this one](http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointArchiveDocs.htm)
- Another way is save the document library as template with Include content options. But this has size limitation.
- Lastly you can write some code to move documents. [check this](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/04/programmatically-copy-and-move-documents-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Ah great so you can just drag and drop a document library without causing an issue - thanks.

Comment: For larger document libraries +/- 50GB what method would you suggest?

Comment: i would go either information management polices or workflow.

Comment: Just looking at the workflow technique - it doesn't seem to store version history? Also I cant see how to achieve moving the whole folder rather than individual files?

Comment: After doing a little further reading, I need to create the folders within the workflow and name them as the name of the folder where the files are to be moved from.